# Need to improve story transition in Instagram story like layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am working on an app that has a story component pretty much like Instagram story.

Whenever I transition from one story to another, there is a very slight delay in which the screen goes blank and then the next image loads. I use Glide caching for loading the images, the effect is more prominent when the load is from disk cache rather than memory. Is there any way I can improve this? How do you think Instagram does it since there is absolutely no perceived delay.

Also for loading the blurred background, in case the image does not fill the entire screen, I use blur transformation on the actual image. And what it usually does is the image loads first and the background loads with slight further delay. For loading the background, should I use some other method? I just read about Palette library. Is that a better solution?

The things that I have tried are mainly improving image load time like caching and moving to image CDN but even with that there will always be some delay. Want to implement in a way such that "by design" there is no delay.

Comment: If you want zero delay you need to preload content so it can be displayed immediately. That means fetching stuff over the network in advance (e.g. the next/previous items), maybe loading a lower res version of several images so you can display something and stream in the full-quality one when required. You probably need to do any processing in advance too (like creating your blurred image) since that could potentially take a moment. You'll have to work out the best way to approach this with your specific case - just bear in mind it's a tradeoff, you can only preload so much

Comment: Thankyou so much for your reply.

Just want to ask is it possible to "preload" views in any way? I mean I am already downloading the image into the cache using Glide. But even with that there is slight delay in loading the image from cache. Is there any way I have the image loaded into the view and just show/hide the view as required. 

Just for example, say I work with 3 views, current previous and next. And populate current and previous views in background and keep them hidden. Do you think this approach is worth it? I understand it will also have some memory overheads.

Comment: I can't really give you any specifics, sorry - it really depends on how Glide works, what options it gives you, whether you have multiple `ImageView`s you're swapping around or just a single one you load all your images into... I'm just giving you avenues to explore really, I don't have any experience with the kind of thing you're trying to do, not with Glide anyway. But separate Views (maybe in a `ViewPager` of some kind) would be worth looking at at least - it's just that large images can use a lot of memory. But you will need at least two for swiping (since you can see both at once)